# Bootstrap 4 Radio / Checkbox Buttons showing Radio and Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 and would like to use the radio and checkbox button groups but the buttons are showing the actual radio and checkbox UI elements as shown below:

[image]

The example above is taken directly out of the documentation. I have tried removing and re-installing Bootstrap 4, removing the site.css file and the open-iconic css all to no avail. I haven't been able to find any links describing this problem.  I am using Chrome version 64.0xxxx and VS 2017 MVC5.

Here is the loading sequence of the CSS and JS files.

[image]

Any help would be most appreciated as I have spent hours trying to track this problem down.

Comment: I've handled a question a few days ago where a guy (as well as his coworker) had a "mystery" that turned out to be an issue with Visual Studio. It's hard for me to believe that Microsoft would allow such a stupid bug to exist and maybe they've fixed it already (I don't use VS myself, so I wouldn't know).

Comment: Try with a different code editor and/or avoid the publishing route in VS. In that case (that I mentioned) VS was messing things up when "publishing" the app/document (which I've never done myself because I've never really used VS).

Comment: What does your template look like? What order are you loading the scripts in? What versions of the relevant libraries are you running? Have you included Popper? Please add your relevant code to showcase a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

The example I was using did not have the "btn-group-toggle" as shown below.

```
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
        </label>
    </div>
```